# Google Script maker to format a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first time posting so bear with me if I leave any crucial details out.

Anyway, to summarize the problem: I have been trying to get a script to work on Google Script maker to format a spreadsheet which is hooked up to a form, to go straight to my email.

So basically User **Form** --> **Spreadsheet** --> **My Email**

The questions are pretty Standard:

1. What's the problem?
2. Where are you located

However the one question I'd like to use is *"What is the priority of this problem?"* High or low. I have it under multiple choice format so its a simple choice.

Psuedocode for what I want:

```
if (priority = low) put #priority low onto the email
```

Simple enough, however I can't seem to get it to work, here's my code:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    
    // Remember to replace XYZ with your own email address
    var email = "email"; 

    var subject = "Help Desk Form Submitted";  

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var message = ""; 
    var priority = "";

    if(message.indexOf("What is the priority of this problem? =           Low")){
        priority += "#priority low";
    }
    else
        priority == "GFHHFFHAHFH ";

    for(var i in headers){
        message += headers[i] + ' =  \t \t'+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";  }

    if (message.indexOf("What is the priority of this problem? =           Low"))
        message += "This is a test";
    else
        message += "This is not a test";

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the first instance of `if(message.indexOf()...`. It's got some problems:

- A few lines earlier, `message` was set to an empty string... so you won't find the "priority" string in it.
- The `if` statement is treating the return of `indexOf()` as a Boolean. However, the return code from `.indexOf()` is `-1` when an item is not found, which is "true-ish". If the string IS found, and is located at the start of the search subject, the return will be `0`, which is "false-ish". If it is found at any other location, the value will be `>0', also "true-ish".
- In the `else`, there's a typo. The comparison `==` should be assignment `=`, or `+=` if you prefer.
- Looking at the surrounding code, this piece looks like it was left-over from a previous version, and can be deleted.

Now look at the second instance.

- The `message` should now be populated. However, the comparison is still using an incorrect Boolean interpretation of `.indexOf()`.
- The search string contains a batch of spaces... but the previous code that looped through responses used tabs to separate the "header" from the "value", so the search will always return '-1' (which will be interpreted as `true`).

There are a couple of other tidy-up items. You probably need:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = "Help Desk Form Submitted";  
  var message = ""; 

  var s = e.range.getSheet(); // Sheet that received form response
  var headers = s.getDataRange().getValues()[0];   

  for (var question in headers) {
    message += headers[question] + ' = \t\t' + e.values[question] + '\n\n';
  }

  // Add text relative to the priority of the reported issue.
  if (e.namedValues["What is the priority of this problem?"].toString() === "Low")
    message += "This is a test";
  else
    message += "This is not a test";

  Logger.log(message);
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 
}
```

PS: You can see why it would be advisable to keep form questions short, like "Priority", and leave the explanatory sentence to be helper text!

Comment: There we go! Thank you. The part that made it work was the

if (e.namedValues["What is the priority of this problem?"].toString() === "Low"), it was the conditions for the if statements that was out of whack. The problem I was having was integrating me learning JS while writing this and putting Google's stuff in there as well. Thanks again!